# How to return a matrix structure from a mex function?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, mex

I have a struct that defines a 3d array, the size is known:

```
struct uchar3
{
  unsigned char x, y, z;
};
```

and I want to return it via mex function in order to use it in matlab like a three dimensional array, like an image. How can this be done?

**EDIT:**

This is apart of the function I use.

```
foo(uchar3 **imagePtr, Mat Im){
unsigned char *cvPtr = Im.ptr<unsigned char>(0);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Im.rows * Im.cols; ++i) {
        (*imagePtr)[i].x = cvPtr[3 * i + 0];
        (*imagePtr)[i].y = cvPtr[3 * i + 1];
        (*imagePtr)[i].z = cvPtr[3 * i + 2];
    }
}
```

**Shai's code:**

```
cv::Mat imageRGB;
    cv::cvtColor(OutPutMat, imageRGB, CV_BGR2RGB);

    // uc3 is populated here 
    mwSize sz[3];
    sz[0] = imageRGB.rows; // matlab is row first
    sz[1] = imageRGB.cols;
    sz[2] = 3;
    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray( 3, sz, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, // create double array, you can change the type here
        mxREAL ); // create real matrix
    float *cvPtr = imageRGB.ptr<float>(0);
    float* p = (float*)mxGetData(plhs[0]); // get a pointer to actual data
    for ( size_t y = 0 ; y < imageRGB.rows ; y++ ) {
        for ( size_t x = 0; x < imageRGB.cols ; x++ ) {
            int i = y * imageRGB.cols + x; // opencv is col first
            p[ x * imageRGB.rows + y ] = cvPtr[3 * i + 0];
            p[ imageRGB.cols * imageRGB.rows + x * imageRGB.rows + y ] = cvPtr[3 * i + 1];
            p[ 2*imageRGB.cols * imageRGB.rows + x * imageRGB.rows + y ] = cvPtr[3 * i + 2];
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you create the array of type `mxDOUBLE_CLASS` then the pointer to its content `p` MUST be of type `double` and NOT `float`. if you want `float` use `mxSINGLE_CLASS`.

Comment: Are you sure your `imageRGB` is of type `float`? is it possible that type of `cvPtr` is `unsigned char`?

Comment: After color transform modification `cv::cvtColor(OutPutMat, imageRGB, CV_BGR2RGB, CV_32F );`it steel crashes.

Comment: shouldn't it be `CV_32F3C`?

Comment: I guess you'll have to debug your mex... good luck. Look here http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-c-c-language-mex-files.html

Comment: If someone wants to work with float I thing you must use mxSINGLE_CLASS. Similarly, If someone wants to work with unsigned char mxUINT8_CLASS must be used. Thanks Shai (+1).

Comment: glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`mxCreateNumericArray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatenumericarray.html)

```
uchar3 uc3;  
// uc3 is populated here 
mwSize sz[3];
sz[0] = Im.rows; // matlab is row first
sz[1] = Im.cols;
sz[2] = 3;
mxArray* pOut = mxCreateNumericArray( 3, sz, mxDOUBLE_CLASS // create double array, you can change the type here
                                      mxREAL ); // create real matrix
double* p = (double*)mxGetData(pOut); // get a pointer to actual data
for ( size_t y = 0 ; y < Im.rows ; y++ ) {
    for ( size_t x = 0; x < Im.cols ; x++ ) {
        int i = y * Im.cols + x; // opencv is col first
        p[ x * Im.rows + y ] = cvPtr[3 * i + 0];
        p[ Im.cols*Im.rows + x * Im.rows + y ] = cvPtr[3 * i + 1];
        p[ 2*Im.cols*Im.rows + x * Im.rows + y ] = cvPtr[3 * i + 2];
    }
}
// set one of your mexFunction's outputs to pOut
```

Comment: The uc3 for me is three dimensional array, a RGB image could you please give a tip?

Comment: @darkmoor how does `uc3` stores the RGB image data if it only has three scalar fields? do you have an array of `uc3`? how big it is?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. In the edit imagePtr is what I want to return.

Comment: I added what exactly i use but it crashes. I will remove it after resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Into your mex function do this :

```
plhs[0] = valueStruct(Test,Test2);
```

Where ValueStruct is a function

```
mxArray* valueStruct(const double& d,const double& d2)
{
    mxArray* p = mxCreateStructMatrix(1,1,2,_fieldnames);

    if (!p)
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("error","Allocation error");

    mxSetField(p,0,"d",mxArray(d));
    mxSetField(p,0,"d2",mxArray(d2));
    return p;
}
```

You can refer to [mxCreateStructMatrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatestructmatrix.html) documentation for more informations.

And for [mxSetField](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxsetfield.html).

For an example, You can refer to mexopencv that create struct with his mxArray class where you can get [here](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/blob/master/src/MxArray.cpp).