# MEX: How to return a matrix from C++/ C to MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

The matrix, that I could return, has only first element correct and all others are zeros. I tried to follow as suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402887/how-to-return-a-matrix-structure-from-a-mex-function); but, it did not workout for me. Some help would be appreciated.

Output:

```
>> Matlab_mex_Testing
B1 =
1.0000        0        0
     0   1.0000        0
     0        0   1.0000
     0        0        0


B =
    1    0    0
    0    0    0
    0    0    0
    0    0    0
```

Matlab code:

```
Dir2  = '/home/dkumar/Mex_Codes_DKU/MexCode_Working/Mex_CPP_N_ARMADILLO_Codes_DKU_makefile_Working';

% MEX
cd(Dir2);
[y, B] = normpdfDKU(1/2,0,1);

%Matlab declared
B1 = eye(4,3)

% Identical matrix returned from MEX
B
```

CPP:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <math.h>

#include "/home/dkumar/armadillo-4.600.3/include/armadillo"
using namespace arma;

using namespace std;

#define pi (3.141592653589793)

extern void _main();

const int numInputArgs  = 3;
const int numOutputArgs = 2;

// Function declarations.
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
double  getMatlabScalar    (const mxArray* ptr);
double& createMatlabScalar (mxArray*& ptr);


int TestingLibraries() ;   // declared and defined in In Include_4_TSNNLS.c and Include_4_TSNNLS.h

// Function definitions.
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
void mexFunction (int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
          int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {

  // Check to see if we have the correct number of input and output
  // arguments.
  if (nrhs != numInputArgs)
    mexErrMsgTxt(" DKU-1: Incorrect number of input arguments");
  if (nlhs != numOutputArgs)
    mexErrMsgTxt("DKU-2: Incorrect number of output arguments");

  // Get the inputs.
  double x  = getMatlabScalar(prhs[0]);
  double mu = getMatlabScalar(prhs[1]);
  double v  = getMatlabScalar(prhs[2]);

  // Create the output. It is also a double-precision scalar.
  double& p = createMatlabScalar(plhs[0]);

  // Compute the value of the univariate Normal at x.
  p = exp(-(x-mu)*(x-mu)/(2*v)) / sqrt(2*pi*v);

  // CREATE ARMA::mat and print 
  mat B = eye<mat>(4,3);

  //Print B
  B.print();

  // Trying to return B as second output
   mwSize sz[2];
   sz[0] = B.n_rows  ; // Matlab is row first
   sz[1] = B.n_cols  ;
   //mxArray* pOUT = mxCreateNumericArray(2, sz, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
   plhs[1] = mxCreateNumericArray(2, sz, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
   //Get a pointer to pOUT
   double* p2 = (double*)mxGetData(plhs[1]);
   *p2 = B[0];

}

double getMatlabScalar (const mxArray* ptr) {

  // Make sure the input argument is a scalar in double-precision.
  if (!mxIsDouble(ptr) || mxGetNumberOfElements(ptr) != 1)
    mexErrMsgTxt("The input argument must be a double-precision scalar");

  return *mxGetPr(ptr);
}

double& createMatlabScalar (mxArray*& ptr) { 
  ptr = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
  return *mxGetPr(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is right here:

```
*p2 = B[0];
```

This is equivalent to only copying the first value of `B` and putting it into the first slot of `p2`, which is the first row, first column of the output.  You need to copy the **entire** matrix over.

Also remember that matrices in MATLAB are **column** major so you need to be cognizant of the way you index into `p2`.   However, [Armadillo states that you access elements in column-major format if you just access the matrices using single linear indices](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access).  Therefore, instead of doing `*p2 = B[0];`, do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < B.n_elem; i++)
    p2[i] = B[i];
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. Since I am not good at C++ and pointer always confuses me, would you please answer one more question?   In, `p2[i] = B[i]; ` the LHS is a **pointer + i increments**; while RHS is an **array**. Why is the compiler not complaining about type mismatch?

Comment: @DushyantKumar `p2[i]` is syntactic sugar for `*(p2 + i)`.  There isn't a type mismatch because doing `p2[i]` does a dereferencing operation. Remember, arrays are contiguous chunks of memory so what you're actually doing when you do `p2[i]` is that you are accessing an element starting at the position where `p2` begins and you move `i` floating-point bytes over.  Array accessing and pointer arithmetic is actually the same thing, but `*(p2 + i)` is actually known to be slightly faster.  However, always write for readability before performance.  Write in the way that is most comfortable to you.